# Create custom control tfs 2015

Tags: javascript, .net, plugins, tfs, tfs-2015

I'm trying to write custom control for workitems (in particular for bugs) in TFS 2015 (its important). i found tutorial: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/custom-control , but they say that **available on VSTS and TFS 2017 or later**

I created the control I needed with the help of the article https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/ui-controls/comboo but my control was added to HUB menu

Is there any possibility to add my control for workItem page (in particular for bugs)? I will be grateful for any information.

Comment: Combo control is for multiple pick or select, What kind of effect do you want to get by the custom control for bug WIT? The custom control for workitems in TFS 2015 is similar as previous versions, you can reference [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/733985/Close-a-Work-Item-Only-if-Child-Work-Items-are-C), And here is a sample for your feference : https://github.com/ambilykk/tfswitcustomcontrols

Comment: I have a server that returns a dynamic list of data. I want to display this list in control (combo box) for items of type Bug. Next, when i select a value, this value must be written to one of the item fields. I already created the control with the [manual](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/custom-control) using js. But I could not place it in WI, only in the hub. can i add my control to WI? or i have to rewrite it using your manual?

Comment: As you mentioned the control you created is only available on VSTS and TFS 2017 or later, it's not available for TFS 2015. You can use [Multivalue control](https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multivalue%20control&referringTitle=Home) to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement, you can use  Multivalue control to achieve that.

Please download the [Multivalue control](https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/) to install it ,then following the [instructions](https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multivalue%20control&referringTitle=Home) to set the list of data as the multiple values.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly, that if I update my tfs server to the 2017 version, I can add the control I wrote by changing the "contributions" section in the manifest file (as in [article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/custom-control)) How in this case i can add it to certain type of WI (bug/case/etc.)?

Comment: @krabcore Yes, as mentioned in the article it is only available on VSTS and TFS 2017 or later. So,if you are update to TFS 2017, then you can follow the tutorial to add the custom control, it will add to all WITs, then you can try to edit the certain type WI definition to hide the control.